# C++ for loop 2D array strange output

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to display this for loop 2d array but I am getting a strange output and I'm not sure what is wrong in my code. I am using an if statement to convert the outer column and row into "x" and the rest should be blank spaces.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {


const int H = 25;
const int W = 82;


char Map[H][W]; // test map display


for(int i = 0; i < H; i++ ){ // display the map
    for(int j = 0; j < W; j++){
        if(i == 0 || i == 24 || j == 0 || j == 81) Map[i][j] = 'x';
        else Map[i][j] = ' ';
        cout << Map[i][j];
    }
}






    return 0;
}
```

The output I am aiming for should look like this

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x                 x
x                 x
x                 x
x                 x
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: What "strange output" do you get?

Comment: you can see the output through this compiler 
http://ideone.com/cBIXOv

Comment: Looks fine to me. Did you want it to print a new line for each value of i?

Comment: Sorry, check the edited question for the output i'm looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you want to print a new line after filling each row:

```
for(int i = 0; i < H; i++ ){ // display the map
    for(int j = 0; j < W; j++){
        if(i == 0 || i == 24 || j == 0 || j == 81) Map[i][j] = 'x';
        else Map[i][j] = ' ';
        cout << Map[i][j];
    }
    cout << '\n';  //<-------- new line
}
```

The computer will only start a new line if you tell it to.

You may need to consider if you wish to store these in the `Map` or not.